# Setting the difficulty value for an IRT model in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to estimate students parameters with items that have existing item parameters. I am using the `ltm` package, but when I try setting the constraints it does not give me the same difficulty values.

Even the example does not seem to set the difficulty values:

```r
ltm(WIRS ~ z1, constr = rbind(c(1, 1, 1), c(6, 2, -0.5)))
```

The output here is:
Coefficients:

```
    Dffclt  Dscrmn
```

Item 1  -0.070  14.259

Item 2   0.121  -0.918

Item 3   3.901   0.225

Item 4  -4.267  -0.296

Item 5   2.374   0.223

Item 6   3.384   0.500

The discrimination value (-0.5) is set (for item 6), but when I get the new values, the difficulty value is not set to 1 (for item 1).  Is there a way to set the difficulty value?

Editing to include the SessionInfo:
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] ltm_1.1-1      polycor_0.7-10 msm_1.6.8      MASS_7.3-51.6  eRm_1.0-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] mvtnorm_1.1-1    lattice_0.20-41  psych_2.0.7      grid_4.0.2       nlme_3.1-148     Matrix_1.2-18
[7] splines_4.0.2    tools_4.0.2      survival_3.1-12  parallel_4.0.2   compiler_4.0.2   colorspace_1.4-1
[13] mnormt_2.0.1     tmvnsim_1.0-2    expm_0.999-5

Comment: Interesting; when I run it, not even the discrimination value is set properly (reflection comes into play and I have the sixth item's discrimination at 0.5). Can you [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I think I finally figured it out - the parameters are not the same, and so you have to use traditional2mirt function in the mirt library to convert the parameters.